# Wix - ignore service failing to start

Tags: service, wix, wix3.9

I'm keeping the "Log On As" info on upgrade for the service I'm installing.

```
     <InstallServices>NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</InstallServices>
     <DeleteServices>NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</DeleteServices>
```

However, the upgrade fails if the user/password are incorrect.

How can I allow my service to fail to start?

I'm able to do this by adding

```
<ServicesStart>0<ServicesStart>
```

and using a custom action to start the services. Although it works, I don't quite like it.

The custom action simply runs a batch file with the following line:

```
net start FoobarService
```

I use quiet execution in the MSI, but running this batch file from the command line I have the following output:

```
System error 1069 has occurred.

The service did not start due to a log-on failure.
```

That's the expected behavior - the upgrade **must** proceed even if the service fails to start. If the service doesn't start, someone will notice it very quickly and will change the credentials.

Comment: In these cases the credentials are typically verified as valid in the UI (or elsewhere) before the install is allowed to proceed. However, I'm not sure why the install fails from StartService and works from a CA (if you are literally just starting the service in the CA). If that's the case the issue may not be the credentials, but a dependency in the GAC or WinSxS because that would cause StartService to fail but a start after InstallFinalize to work.

Comment: This can be reproduced (I think) with any service. Just add incorrect user/pass and it will fail to start. Added more info in my question.

Comment: Of course it fails to start. But your original post says you used a custom action to start the service and it works. That's not what you'd see if the credentials were incorrect. If they are incorrect they are incorrect and it would make no difference who started the service. The credentials need validating with a custom action if they can be entered incorrectly, as I said. If you search for -validate username and password-  there are many code examples. Not sure what else I can add.